# Samsung S3 mini NFC Service has Stopped (4.1.2)

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I was working with NFC in my application and I have tested on samsung s4, nexus 4, xperia z3 and it worked perfectly.  However, testing on an s3 mini the callback seems to loop and then a popup occurs saying NFC service has stopped working.

I was worried that it may be my code causing this issue, however, outside the app, I tried to send across a photo and the same issue occurred.  The s3 mini is running 4.1.2.  Has anyone com across this before, I've encountered a few cases online and I'm wondering if it's a 4.1.2 issue?

Comment: I finally managed to find the reason for this.  During the nfc transfer I was alpha animating an image on screen and for some reason this caused this crash.  I was stopping the animation in the nfc call back so I don't know why but this is what caused this crash.  It may not be the case if you experience this issue but it's something to look at